# How to identify rows where two columns have match exactly in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

My question may sound weird, but please bear with me. This is what I have:

Table Products:

---

```
ProductName     Cost   
Pen A           1.00  
Pen A           1.00  
Pen B           1.00   
Pen A           2.00  
Pen C           3.00  
Pen C           3.00  
Pen C           3.00
```

How do I remove true duplicates from this? If you look at the data, you can see that Pen C has three rows with exact same data. Pen A has 2 rows with same data and 1 with a different cost. I don't want to eliminate "Pen A".

A simple group by statement like this:

```
SELECT ProductName,Cost FROM PRODUCTS GROUP BY ProductName,Cost HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

This wont' work since it'll pick up "PEN A" as well.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: what's the expected result? Why doesn't `SELECT DISTINCT ProductName,Cost FROM PRODUCTS` not return what you want?

Comment: Let this be a lesson to always create a `PRIMARY KEY` in tables.

Answer (score 1):

A quick way without using join or subqueries is to create a table PRODUCTS_TEMP  with the same structure and insert just the unique rows:

```
INSERT INTO PRODUCTS_TEMP 
SELECT DISTINCT ProductName,Cost FROM PRODUCTS;
```

Then you can delete your PRODUCTS table and rename PRODUCTS_TEMP to PRODUCTS:

```
DROP TABLE PRODUCTS;
ALTER TABLE PRODUCTS_TEMP RENAME TO PRODUCTS;
```

Now you have your table filtered.

Comment: * Note I'm using Mysql syntax since I don't have a sqlServer instance ready for testing. Feel free to update this if you find any incompatibilities.

Comment: Also need to remember to script PKs, FKs, indexes, and triggers, if applicable. If any of these are required, I'd go with John's answer.

Comment: No need for the temp table, but I agree `DISTINCT` is the easiest method here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `CTE` in concert with `Row_Number()` to remove Dupes

**Example**

```
;with cte as (
    Select * 
          ,RN = Row_Number() over (Partition By ProductName,Cost Order By (Select null))
    from PRODUCTS 
)
Delete from cte where RN>1
```

**Updated Table**

```
ProductName Cost
Pen A       1.00
Pen B       1.00
Pen A       2.00
Pen C       3.00
```

Answer (score 0):

After cleaning the mess in any way you like, you might like to consider to create a constraint index there with that 2 columns and/or validate to get sure that combination doesn't exists before inserting new rows.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I think you want products that have only one cost.  If so:

```
select productname
from products
group by productname
having min(cost) = max(cost);
```